# How to apply sortable header to a table-style and paginated view?

Tags: 7, views

I have a table of 250 employees created with views. It is sorted by their name. I'd like to sort it by other fields as well therefore I made them sortable in the view settings page. I also set it paginated (50 items per page).

When I click on the header of a sortable field the order changes as expected. But if I go to the 2nd page, several records from the 1st page appear again so the table becomes totally inconsistent. Is it possible to fix it somehow?